# How to check a file is opened or closed in R

Tags: r, file

I would like to ask how can I check a file's status (whether it is opened or closed) before reading in R programming?

I have tried `myfile = open(filenames)`; it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

I think the trick is to use `open = "w"` to open for writing. This seems to work perfectly for me:

```
file.opened <- function(path) {
  suppressWarnings(
    "try-error" %in% class(
      try(file(path, 
               open = "w"), 
          silent = TRUE
      )
    )
  )
}
```

After I open an Excel file:

```
file.opened("C:\\Folder\\tbl1.xlsx")
# TRUE
```

And when I close it:

```
file.opened("C:\\Folder\\tbl1.xlsx")
# FALSE
```

Comment: When I run this function, it corrupts the Excel file. Sometimes I'll still be able to open the file after one or two uses, but the problem happens later if I keep using it. Trying to open it with Excel gives "The file format or file extension is not valid," and using openxlsx::read.xlsx() gives: "Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In unzip(xlsxFile, exdir = xmlDir) : error 1 in extracting from zip file"

Comment: That's strange, I never got this problem. Do you get this with any Excel file?

Comment: Yes, even empty files that I've just created. I'm using Excel 365.

Comment: Beware: Currently this code always corrupts files when checked. Maybe it's a version issue. I almost lost very crucial data.

Comment: `file(path, open = "w")` seems to overwrite the existing file with a blank file. `file(path, open = "r+")` still tries to open the file for writing, but doesn't actually write anything to it (ie. leaves the existing data there). See the modes section in `?file`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the function `file` a connection to the file is returned:

```
con <- file(description="path/to/file", ...)
```

You can check to see if this is open using the `isOpen` function, which will return a `logical` (`TRUE`, `FALSE`, or `NA`).

If you don't have a `connection` in your R session, or the connection has been deleted, then the connection is closed:

An excerpt of `?file`:

```
 ‘close’ closes and destroys a connection.  This will happen
 automatically in due course (with a warning) if there is no longer
 an R object referring to the connection.
```

File connections can be opened and closed using `open` and `close` respectively.

Comment: Basically you want to use `file` not `open` :)

Comment: I tried with a MS-Word doc and it didn't work. `isOpen` returns `FALSE`, whether the doc is open or not.

Comment: @DanChaltiel `isOpen` does not check whether a file is open in any application, it checks whether a specific connection is open in R, e.g. in the case above, the `con` variable.

Comment: In general you can't check whether a file is currently open in another program. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951791/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-already-open-by-another-process-in-c for some discussion on this

Answer (score 0):

For Excel files, I used the following approach and it works in my computer : rename the Excel file with it's name. If the Excel file is opened, it returns FALSE. If the Excel file is closed, it returns TRUE.

```
file.rename(from = "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Test file access/file1.xlsx",
            to = "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Test file access/file1.xlsx")
```