# safely test if file is open via R

Tags: r, file, connection

I want to safely test if a file (e.g., called `test.docx`) is open using `R`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50966628/4083743) proposes a solution but the associated comments complain that it corrupts the file. I too find it corrupts the file and results in a blank `docx` when I use it on `test.docx`.

Code to produce an example `docx` file using `rmarkdown` (called `test.Rmd`):

```
---
title: "test"
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
---


# heading 1

# heading 2
```

render call:

```
library(bookdown)
library(officedown)
library(officer)
rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd', 
                  output_format = 'rdocx_document')
```

Using the proposed solution to test if open:

```
file.opened <- function(path) {
  suppressWarnings(
    "try-error" %in% class(
      try(file(path, 
               open = "w"), 
          silent = TRUE
      )
    )
  )
}
file.opened("test.docx")
# [1] FALSE
```

It correctly returns `FALSE` as I have not opened the file yet, but the file has now been edited and is blank (size of file reduced to `0`).

What is a safe way to test if it is open or not?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `file(path, open = "r+")` as in the comments of the answer you linked? That seems to work for me. Also I would do change your function to `try(con  <- file(path, open = "r+"), silent = TRUE)` and then add `on.exit(close(con))` to the function body to ensure unused connections are cleaned up.

Comment: thanks, I saw that but I wanted to make sure that it was a fully safe approach that wasn't doing anything unknowingly in the background. Could you share the full function code that includes `on.exit(close(con))` so that it returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending if its open or closed please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Hadley Wickham writes in [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/conditions.html):

> It is possible, but not recommended, to save the result of `try()` and perform different actions based on whether or not the code succeeded or failed. Instead, it is better to use `tryCatch()`.

This is how I would write this function:

```r
is_file_open <- function(path, mode = "r+b") {
  tryCatch(
    {
        con  <- suppressWarnings(file(path, open = mode))
        on.exit(close(con))
        FALSE
    },
    error = function(e) TRUE
  )
}
```

We can open the file with mode `"r+b"`. From the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html) for `file()`:

> `"r+"` `"r+b"`: Open for reading and writing.

As docx is binary we should use `b` though I don't think it matters if you're not writing to the file. This gives the correct output and does not delete the contents of the file.

Furthermore, with your previous function, if you run it a few times and then run `showConnections()`, it will print something like `Warning message: In .Internal(gc(verbose, reset, full)) :closing unused connection 4 (test.docx)`. We can avoid that by explicitly closing the connection when we exit the function.

```r
# With the file open in MS Word
is_file_open("test.docx")
# [1] TRUE

# With the file not open
is_file_open("test.docx")
# [1] FALSE
```

#### A better function

A problem with this `is_file_open()` approach, however, is that it returns `TRUE` if it encounters any error. This may not be an issue in this case, but you can't actually use the function to reliably test if a file is open.

I think it would be better to have a function like this:

```r
can_write_to_file <- function(path, mode = "r+b") {
    if(!file.exists(path)) {
        warning("The file does not exist. Checking if it can be created.")
        tryCatch(
            {   
                # Check if we can write to a non-existent file
                close(suppressWarnings(file(path, open = "w")))
                # If we can then delete the empty file
                unlink(path)
                return(TRUE)
            },
            error = function(e) return(FALSE)
        )
    }
  # Check whether an existing file can currently be written to
  tryCatch(
    {
        close(suppressWarnings(file(path, open = mode)))
        TRUE
    },
    error = function(e) FALSE
  )
}
```

This does what a user would expect from the function name.

Comment: @user63230 I tried to keep the code pretty simple and similar to your original. I think technically you should rename the function and reverse `TRUE` and `FALSE` - see my edit.